# Split a pandas dataframe into many smaller frames (chunks) and save them

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called `df` which is 1364 rows (this includes the title).

The first row is the column names so that leaves 1363 rows.

I want to split it up into `n` frames (each frame should have the column names as well) and save them as csv files.

So let's say n is 30, `1363/30` = `45.433`.

I created logic to round up the 45.433 to 46. Then calculate how many rows should be in the remaining frame. Basically it checks if the number of rows is divisible by n. If it is, it will do the `else` part, other wise it will calculate the remainder from rounding up. So in this case, for 1363, there will be 29 frames with 46 rows, and 1 remaining frame with 29 `(1363-(29*46))` rows

```
length = len(df) #length is 1363
n = 30 

if length % n != 0:
    numrows = int(length / n) + (length % n > 0)
    remaindernumrows = length - (numrows * (n-1))
    row_counter = 1
    splitdf = pd.DataFrame()
    frame_counter = 0

    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if frame_counter != (n - 1):
            splitdf = splitdf.append(row)
            row_counter += 1
            print(idx, row['Name'])

            if row_counter == numrows:
                frame_counter += 1
                splitdf.to_csv(
                    f"/Users/XXX/Documents/frames/frame-{frame_counter}.csv",
                    index=False)
                splitdf = pd.DataFrame()
                row_counter = 1

        else:
            splitdf = splitdf.append(row)
            row_counter += 1
            print(idx, row['Name'])

            if row_counter == remaindernumrows:
                frame_counter += 1
                splitdf.to_csv(
                    f"/Users/XXX/Documents/frames/frame-{frame_counter}.csv",
                    index=False)
                splitdf = pd.DataFrame()
                row_counter = 1


else:
    numrows = int(length / n) + (length % n > 0)
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        splitdf = splitdf.append(row)
        row_counter += 1
        print(idx, row['Name'])

        if row_counter == numrows:
            frame_counter += 1
            splitdf.to_csv(
                f"/Users/XXX/Documents/frames/frame-{frame_counter}.csv",
                index=False)
            splitdf = pd.DataFrame()
            row_counter = 1
```

I think my code works fine, but I want to know if there is a better way to do this with built in pandas functions because my code feels very clunky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind saving the full `dataframe` first then you can try this.
Read the `dataframe` back in chunks using `chunksize` then save each chunk separately inside the loop.

```
n=30
reader = pd.read_csv('savedFrame.csv',chunksize=n)
for chunk in reader:
    chunk.to_save('path')
```

Comment: I can do this, please keep this answer, but is there also a way to do it without saving it?

Comment: Sure, let's see if others have a different way to do this esp without saving. This one save you a lot of code.